# Create new div based in others

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code

```
<div class="tabbable">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab"></ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
             <div id="rede" class="tab-pane fade in active">
             <div id="produto" class="tab-pane fade">
       </div>
</div>
```

I need separate div "rede" and "produto" in new divs, for example:

```
<div class="tabbable">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab"></ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
                 <div id="rede" class="tab-pane fade in active">
           </div>
    </div>
<div class="tabbable">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab"></ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
             <div id="produto" class="tab-pane fade">
       </div>
</div>
```

I need separate using javascript, jquery.

Comment: Did you try to write some code for that?

Comment: No, I didn´t.  I need help how to do. Tks

Comment: So you are looking for a javascript/jquery tutorial? Or you are looking for someone to do your homework for you?

Comment: I´m looking javascript/jquery, but I have not found a solution yet.

Comment: You can learn javascript with [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/js/) and jquery with [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/). Try to write something yourself and when you are stuck it will be easier to help with a specific problem.

Comment: Hi, I got it. 
 $(selector).find(".tabbable").parent().replaceWith(newContent); Tks

Comment: Great. You can answer your own question :)

Answer (score 1):

I got it. $(selector).find(".tabbable").parent().replaceWith(newContent);